# Create a string in MySQL using an input parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

Having an input parameter, for example `num = 3`, I want to create a string in MySQL, concatenated by ','.

In Python it would look like this:

```
num = 3

string = ['target_table']
for i in range(num):
    string.append('hub_hid_column_' + str(i))
    string.append('hub_hid_column_name_' + str(i))

print(','.join(string))
```

At the end i want to have the following output: `target_table,hub_hid_column_0,hub_hid_column_name_0,hub_hid_column_1,hub_hid_column_name_1,hub_hid_column_2,hub_hid_column_name_2`

How can i do it in MySQL? Ideally without a procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
WITH RECURSIVE num AS (
  SELECT 1 AS n
  UNION
  SELECT n+1 FROM num WHERE n < 3 -- here is where you change your number
)
SELECT CONCAT('target_table,', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('hub_hid_column_',n-1,',hub_hid_column_name_',n-1))) AS list
FROM num;
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| list                                                                                                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| target_table,hub_hid_column_0,hub_hid_column_name_0,hub_hid_column_1,hub_hid_column_name_1,hub_hid_column_2,hub_hid_column_name_2 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

While SQL is great for certain tasks, other languages may be better suited to this task.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!